# Inserting data into a stats table with merge - An action of type 'INSERT' is not allowed in the 'WHEN MATCHED' clause of a MERGE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I have two tables

The first table

```
stats {
Id, 
stat1 decimal,
stat2 decimal,
stat3 decimal,
[LastChangeDate] datetime2
}
```

The second table

```
statsHistory {
Id, 
stat1 decimal,
stat2 decimal,
stat3 decimal,
[LastChangeDate] datetime2
DateGenerated Date
}
```

The statsHistory table is designed to be a caching of the daily stats data to reduce the recalculation of the daily stats based on session data.

I'm trying to use a merge statement to pull the data from the stats table into the statsHistory table. I intend to have this stored procedure called nightly at a set time.

```
;WITH C1 AS (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY uc.Id ORDER BY [DayDateGenerated] DESC) as rowNumber,
        uc.[Id]
      ,uc.[stat1]
      ,uc.[stat2]
      ,uc.[stat3]
      ,UCH.DayDateGenerated
UCH.[stat1]
      ,UCH.[stat2]
      ,UCH.[stat3]

  FROM
  [UserConcepts] as uc
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [UserConceptsDayHistory] as UCH on 
  UCH.[MemberId] = uc.[MemberId] AND UCH.[ForConceptId] = uc.[MemberId]
)
  

Merge [UserConceptsDayHistory] AS TARGET
  USING(  
    select * from C1
    WHERE rowNumber = 1
    --AND CONVERT(DATE,[LastChangeDate]) < CONVERT(DATE,DateAdd(GetUtcDAte(),-1))
  ) AS source
  ON(target.[MemberId] = source.[MemberId] AND target.[ForConceptId] = source.[ForConceptId])
  WHEN not MATCHED THEN
        insert(stat1
      ,stat2
      ,stat3
      ,[LastChangeDate]
      ,DateGenerated
)
      values
      (source.stat1
      ,source.stat2
      ,source.stat3
      ,source.[LastChangeDate]
      ,source.[LastChangeDate]
      )
     WHEN  MATCHED  AND  source.DayDateGenerated = target.DayDateGenerated AND source.[TotalSessions] != target.[TotalSessions] THEN
     update SET 
     stat1 = source.stat1
      ,stat2= source.stat2 - target.stat3
      ,stat3  = source.stat3
      ,[LastChangeDate]  = source.[LastChangeDate],
    DateGenerated = source.[LastChangeDate] 

       WHEN  MATCHED  AND  source.DayDateGenerated IS NOT NULL  AND  source.DayDateGenerated != target.DayDateGenerated THEN
        insert(stat1
      ,stat2
      ,stat3
      ,[LastChangeDate]
      ,DateGenerated
)
      values
      (source.stat1
      ,source.stat2 - target.stat3
      ,source.stat3
      ,source.[LastChangeDate]
      ,source.[LastChangeDate]
      )
      
      OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;
```

As the history table could have many rows I had hoped to have conditional match cases where I could insert where a row existed in the table but not for that date, however, I get the following SQL error:

> An action of type 'INSERT' is not allowed in the 'WHEN MATCHED' clause of a MERGE statement

I understand that I cannot achieve what I was hoping for with the merge statement, however, was wondering if there are any good alternative approaches to this issue.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: The alternative to a `MERGE` is an "Upsert", which some expects recommend over it anyway, considering the caveats that come with the `MERGE` statement. [So you want to use `MERGE`, eh?](//sqlblog.org/merge)

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish - but this looks like something a temporal table would resolve.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @Jeff I'm trying to generate a stats table that contains the aggregated stats for the original table on a daily basis. The StatsHistory table will have a number of addition attributes stored in the table that are not in the original stats table which is why a temporal table is not suitable in this instance. An number of the additional attributes will be derived from the attributes on the original table. I was hoping to use merge to allow me to conditionally insert into this table from the original.

Comment: @Larnu I guess re writing this as an upsert with conditionals wouldn't be such a bad thing.  I just liked the thought of using Merge for it as if it had worked how I thought it would have been cleaner.

Comment: MichaelLeipper, the MERGE statement has some pitfalls, described in the article mentioned by @Larnu, but the clean idea, in reference to the MATCHED part of your code, is like below: when the source and the target match, then do UPDATE. This is not a general conditional structure like IF/ELSE, when the body can be anything, but it is strictly aligned to the simple problem of matching source and target. If you need a more flexible solution, you will do better to follow the mentioned article.